# Displaying info messages using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have to display info message in the attached image format.i have seen codes for error messages in jQuery. I tried with `ui-state-info` class but i couldn't get the exact thing as below.

The code I have tried is

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
 <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" 
            style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: INFO MESSAGE FORMAT]

Comment: Can you please provide us with a [mcve] of your current code?

Comment: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsLHL.png) when I try to use your code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar where you ran the code?

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban Using jQuery UI Widget...

Comment: @PraveenKumar You local pc or any website? If website can you please share the link?

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban Local PC boss...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
 <div class="ui-state-info ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;"> 
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" 
            style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Information:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly did you change?

Comment: Same, it looks the same to me.

Comment: class name from *ui-icon-alert* to *ui-icon-info* and *ui-state-alert* to *ui-state-info*

Comment: how to get the box and background color?.i know it can be done through css but my ask is there any class in jquery ui css?

Comment: @DivyaS I believe they are available in Bootstrap instead of jQuery UI. Any possibility that you could grab the code from there to use it here?